# How to watch the valueChanges of a form and get the form control name?

Tags: angular

I have a method that filters an array depending on the value of a select and filters it by the property that has the same name as the form control.

```
filterLum(val: string | number, c: AbstractControl | string): void {
     const formGroup = c.parent.controls;
     const name = Object.keys(formGroup).find((name) => c === formGroup[name]) || null;
     return this.data.filter(x => x[name] === val);
  }
```

For this I have a valueChanges in each of the form controls that can make a filter. Like this

```
this.valueWatcherSubscription = this.form
      .get('status')
      .valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribeSignal.asObservable()))
      .subscribe((val) =>
        val ? this.filterLum(val, this.form.get('status')) : null
      );
```

The problem is that I have more than 15 form Controls and for each one I have a watcher. So I made a watcher for all the formControls that interact with the array. Like this:

```
const exclude: string[] = ['default'];
    const keys = [];
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
      if (exclude.findIndex(q => q === key) === -1) {
        keys.push(this.form.get(key).valueChanges);
      }
    });
    const valueWatcherSubscription = merge(...keys);
    valueWatcherSubscription.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

But here **val** only gets the value of the select, but I also need the name of the form where does it come from, is there a way to also take the **form.get('form.control')**? So that I can use the filterLum function in each control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a several ways to accomplish this.  Keeping with what you have, the smallest change would be to have your observables return an object with both pieces of info (the `name` and `value`), rather than just returning the value provided by valueChanges:

```
    const exclude: string[] = ['default'];
    const keys = [];
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach(key => {
      if (exclude.findIndex(q => q === key) === -1) {
        keys.push(this.form.get(key).valueChanges.pipe(
          map(val => ({name: key, value: val})) // <------
        ));
      }
    });
    const valueWatcherSubscription = merge(...keys);
    valueWatcherSubscription.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

Instead of having a separate array (`keys`) and using `forEach` to fill it, you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array of fields into an array of observables.

Also, using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) provides the property and the value, in your case the `name` and the `formControl`, so you could use that instead of looking up the form control within your logic (`this.form.get(key)`):

```
    const exclude: string[] = ['default'];

    const controlWatchers = Object.entries(this.form.controls)
      .filter(([key]) => !exclude.includes(key))
      .map(([name, control]) => control.valueChanges.pipe(
         map(value => ({ name, value }))
      ));
    );
    const formWatcher$ = merge(...controlWatchers);
    formWatcher$.subscribe(console.log);
```

And one last way would be to generate an observable using `from()`:

```
    const exclude: string[] = ['default'];

    const formWatcher$ = from(Object.entries(this.form.controls)).pipe(
      filter(([key]) => !exclude.includes(key))
      mergeMap(([name, control]) => control.valueChanges.pipe(
         map(value => ({ name, value }))
      ));
    );
    formWatcher$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But here val only gets the value of the select, but I also need the name of the form where does it come from, is there a way to also take the form.get('form.control')? So that I can use the filterLum function in each control?

Yes, you can get the form controls using **form.controls[key]**